# Specifying alternative location for config.json

Tags: docker

When I run the docker command like docker push, how can I specify, that other `config.json` should be used as `~/.docker/config.json` ?

I want to push to the multiple docker registries, and fetch for each of this registry a config.json from vault with credentials to only that registry, instead of one with all possible logins, so I need to use different `config.json`'s in the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at their tests then you can see they use a different `HOME` directory in such cases

https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/7b9275c0da707b030e62c96b679a976f31f929d3/integration-cli/docker_cli_run_unix_test.go#L256

```golang
dotDocker := filepath.Join(tmpDir, ".docker")
os.Mkdir(dotDocker, 0600)
tmpCfg := filepath.Join(dotDocker, "config.json")

defer func() { os.Setenv(homeKey, homeVal) }()
os.Setenv(homeKey, tmpDir)

data := `{
   "detachKeys": "ctrl-a,a"
}`
```

So you should be able to do something similar

```sh
$ HOME=repoa docker push XYZ
```

You may have to write few wrapper functions to get what you want